# How do I implement this regular expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I make a Javascript regular expression that will take this string (named `url_string`):

```
http://localhost:3000/new_note?date1=01-01-2010&date2=03-03-2010
```

and return it, but with the value of the `date1` parameter set to a new date variable, which is called `new_date_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to manipulate URL than regex, but a simple solution like this may work:

```
after = before.replace(/date1=[\d-]+/, "date1=" + newDate);
```

`[\d-]+` matches a non-empty sequence of digits and/or dashes. If you really need to, you can also be more specific with e.g. `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`, or an even more complicated date regex that rejects invalid dates, etc.

Note that since the regex makes the `"date1="` prefix part of the match, it is also substituted in as part of the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but:

```
var url_string = "http://localhost:3000/new_note?date1=01-01-2010&date2=03-03-2010";
var new_date_1 = "01-02-2003";

var new_url_string = url_string.replace(/date1=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/, "date1="+new_date_1);
/* http://localhost:3000/new_note?date1=01-02-2003&date2=03-03-2010 */
```

There must be a proper URL parser in JS. Have a Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
url.replace(/date1=[0-9-]{10}/, "date1=" + new_date_1);
```